# Unable to select ListItem from a dynamic list

Tags: android, android-layout, mocking, robotium, ui-testing

I am trying to test my application, where in a text-box some string (say "xyz") will be entered and a list of suggestions will come (which is fetched from server). Out of those I want to select the 1st one, but I am getting java language error. My code is

```
EditText input = solo.getView(R.id.inputBox);
        solo().clickOnView(input);
        solo().enterText(input, "XYZ");
        solo().sendKey(Solo.ENTER);
        solo().waitForDialogToClose(20000);
        solo().clickInList(0);
```

If I give `sleep` command berofe `solo().sendKey(Solo.ENTER)` then I can that "**XYZ**" has been entered in editbox and the time when ENTER is triggered, the test ends and error can be seen in failure tracer (in Junit eclips).

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getEditText().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // What you want
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, my app is working fine.But, the problem is with my **Robotium** test cases. If I perform the actions manually, this executes well and fine, but the time when I try to do Robotium Test, it fails due to above reasons.